# IBM Integration Bus requires broker restart to setup new log with log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, ibm-integration-bus

Our ESB is IBM IIB 9. We use log4j to log messages.

I am sure that I am doing something wrong when setting up logging because whenever new log needs to be setup the entire broker has to be taken down which is mind boggling.

Does broker really needs to be restarted? Can someone point me to the documentation on how to setup log4j for a specific integration server, so I wouldn't have to bounce broker?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you have to restart the jvm for new log4j configurations to take effect. As each execution group has its own process, restarting the execution group should be enough, you don't have to restart the entire broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest log4j library i.e. log4j v2.11
This gives you the option of having a configuration file where you can set an interval during which the broker would scan the configuration file for any changes and load the changes accordingly. 
Additionally, you can also set system variables to set some logging specific properties. Refer to the Apache documentation for more details.